# Visual Studio Code - failed to create temp directory

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

New to programming and to Visual Studio Code..
I'm just learing the first commands but I can't manage that my IDE work..
I tried using Spyder, and shutsdown by itself. And now, VSC is giving me problems.

```
PS D:\> & conda run -p  --no-capture-output --live-stream python d:/T7A.py
usage: conda-script.py run [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH][-v][--dev]
[--debug-wrapper-scripts] [--cwd CWD] [--no-capture-output]
[--live-stream]...conda-script.py run: error: argument -p/prefix:expected one argument
```

I don't know what it means or I could solve it... I tried to chance the directory, using other drive, and also using a pendrive, it didn't work either..

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UApq8.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. In particular, please make sure to actually ask a question. Wwhat does "giving me problems" mean?

Answer (score 0):

`conda run` means:

```
Run an executable in a conda environment. [Experimental]
```

`-p PATH, --prefix PATH`:

```
Full path to environment location
```

And

```
--no-capture-output   Don't capture stdout/stderr

--live-stream         Display the output for the subprocess stdout and stderr on real time.
```

Error:

```
error: argument -p/prefix:expected one argument
```

So, you need to give an conda environment path to `-p`

For example:

```
conda run -p C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\env01  --no-capture-output --live-stream python C:\Work\python3.10\hello\a.py
```

But I don't know why you execute this command in the terminal, you can right-click and select `Run Python File in Terminal`, or execute it likes `python pythonFilePath` in the terminal.

**Update:**

Very sorry for that, I haven't noticed after you select the conda environment then you select `Run Python in Terminal` will execute this kind of command.

But my command was a little different from yours, it looks like this:

```
& conda run -n base --no-capture-output --live-stream python c:/Work/python3.10/hello/a.py

& conda run -n env01 --no-capture-output --live-stream python c:/Work/python3.10/hello/a.py
```

Instead of `-p`, it takes `-n`. I could not find what's the reason for your command. Could you attach a screenshot of it?

And for now, you can switch the environment from `conda` to a basic python interpreter such as `venv` as a workaround. And you can refer to the [official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_create-a-virtual-environment) for the basic knowledge of `venv`.

Or you can try to reinstall the Python extension or install the older version of it.

Comment: I'm not trying to execute this command. It is the output error that gave me from executing some basic python exercises...

Comment: @PedroMTG How do you execute it?

Comment: Run Python File

Comment: @PedroMTG Very sorry for being late, like I have mentioned in the answer, you can right-click in the VSCode, and then select `Run  Python File in Terminal` or to click the `Run Button` at the top-left on the VSCode.

Comment: @PedroMTG Very sorry for that, could you have a look at the update of the answer? thanks a lot. Sorry for my delay again.