# I have a problem when trying to run script using anaconda in Visual studio code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When running visual studio code on my computer I get this error

```
                       usage: conda-script.py run [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-v] [--dev]

                       [--debug-wrapper-scripts] [--cwd CWD]
                       [--no-capture-output] [--live-stream]
                       ...
                       conda-script.py run: error: argument -p/--prefix: expected one argument
```

Comment: install vscode directly from the website: https://code.visualstudio.com/download

Comment: That still doesn't work. I reinstalled it and get the same error.

Comment: what is the code that you are executing ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone had run across a similar problem, you can refer to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371141/visual-studio-code-failed-to-create-temp-directory/71376064#71376064). But I can not reproduce it.

The updates of the Python extension about one month ago, takes `conda run` to replace `python`:

> Use conda run for conda environments for running python files and
> installing modules. ([#18479](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/18479))

[changelog](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items/ms-python.python/changelog)(28 February 2022).

It has some problems(you can refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391476/vscode-uses-different-system-paths-for-python-with-run-command-and-debugger/71405347#71405347) for more details):

[conda run -n MY-ENV python FILE.py uses the base interpreter instead of environment interpreter.](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9587)

But it's different from yours.

You can try these as a workaround:

1. Switch the anaconda environment to the venv environment.
2. Reinstall the python extension or install some early version.

And it will be helpful if you can provide more details, then we can try to find out the reason for this problem.